# Android Layout Setting Height to a specific percentage of its container?

Tags: android

I would like to set an inner layout that is included in a relative layout to a specific percentage of the layout it is included in.  How can I set the layout height to a specific percentage. 
Another example lets say I have an ImageView and I want it to take up exactly 60% of the container that it is within.  How can I specify this?  I did see: [Android Layout Percentage/Proportion Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693787/android-layout-percentage-proportion-resize) which somewhat explains this. However if I wanted say 48% I am not sure adjust weight would work?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `LinearLayout` instead, with the property `android:layout_weigth`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

    <!-- Other elements here -->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The nested `RelativeLayout` will ocuppy 2 / (2 + 3) = 0.4 (40%), and the `ImageView` 3 / (2 + 3) = 0.6 (60%).

Comment: A simpler example would be to exclude the `weightSum` altogether and to simply have weights of 0.4 and 0.6. Without an explicit `weightSum` the layout inflation process calculates the total of all weights and then adjust accordingly. In other words, 0.4 + 0.6 = 1 and they are each repectively 40% and 60% of 1.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Agree. For some reason I got used to think them as integer values. That is useful for more complex distributions, like _"three elements, one of which is five times bigger than each of the other two"_, then you have weights of 5 / 1 / 1.

Comment: Yes, I can see your logic. Generally I work on percentages so an implicit total weight of 1 will suffice and I adjust accordingly. With more than two elements and more complex layouts than the OP describes, the explicit `weightSum` and integers would make a lot of sense.